# How to get the Rows cell value from columnHeaderNames in excel using c#

Tags: c#, excel, interop, excel-2010

my requirement is to read the rows of a specified column from an excel sheet. eg

[image]

from the above excel if i need to get rows values of column (ie) **B** how to get it.
am getting the column header names using the below code.

```
     Excel.Application xlApp = new Excel.Application();
        Excel.Workbook xlWorkbook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(FileNameTextBox.Text);
        Excel.Worksheet xlWorksheet = xlWorkbook.Sheets[1]; // assume it is the first sheet
        int columnCount = xlWorksheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count;
        List<string> columnNames = new List<string>();
        for (int c = 1; c < columnCount; c++)
        {
            if (xlWorksheet.Cells[1, c].Value2 != null)
            {
                string columnName = xlWorksheet.Columns[c].Address;
                Regex reg = new Regex(@"(\$)(\w*):");
                if (reg.IsMatch(columnName))
                {
                    Match match = reg.Match(columnName);
                    columnNames.Add(match.Groups[2].Value);
                }
            }
        }
```

where it gives me a output of  list contains A,B,C,D,E,F .from this if i need to get the value of column **C** alone ,then how to get it..?

Answer (score 0):

HRD in your connection Staring should be NO to access the header data then use 1st loop for Row and inner loop in the 1st Loop to access Cells of the Row.

```
"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + fileLocation + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0;HDR=No;IMEX=2\"";
```

Answer (score 0):

This Method returns the values of cells in the first row of an excel sheet:

```
public static string[] FirstRowInWorkSheet(string filename, int sheetNumber)
    {
        Application xlsApp = new Application();
        Workbook wb = xlsApp.Workbooks.Open(filename,
            0, true, 5, "", "", true, XlPlatform.xlWindows, "\t", false, false, 0, true);

        var sheets= wb.Worksheets;
        Worksheet xlWorksheet =sheets[sheetNumber]; 

        int columnCount = xlWorksheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count;
        Range xlRange = xlWorksheet.UsedRange;
        string[] firstRow = new string[columnCount];

        for (int c = 0; c < columnCount; c++)
        {
            if (xlRange.Cells[1, c + 1].Value2 != null)
            {
                firstRow[c] = xlRange.Cells[1, c + 1].Value2.ToString();
            }
        }
        return firstRow;
    }
```

This code helps you get the header of your table as an array. When the user selects the column, take its index, and then manipulate the cells for one column- the same way it was manipulated for the 1st row- just change what you fix in Cell[i,j]: fix j according to what the user choose.